# Can't load external stylesheet using dash-bootstrap after clearing browser cache

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, plotly-dash

I'm using `dash-bootstrap-components` and external stylesheets for my navbar. The third line in my code is literally

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__,use_pages=True,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.CERULEAN, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP],suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
```

This worked fine UNTIL I decided to clear the cache of my browser. Everything broke and I don't know why nor have any idea why the bootstrap components won't 're-cache' again. I have the the following situation or from situation 1 I went to situation 2 just by clearing the cache:
[image]

Has anyone ever stumbled upon an issue like this? How can I resolve this thing, it literally broke by itself, lol

Answer (score 0):

It fixed after I manually accessed the stylesheet's URL (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@5.3.1/dist/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css).

That being the solution points out to potential network issues.